# How do I extract a section number and the text after it?

Tags: r

I have a question.

My text file contains lines such as:

```
1.1        Description. 
This is the description.

1.1.1      Quality Assurance 
Random sentence.

1.6.1    Quality Control. Quality Control is the responsibility of the contractor.
```

I'm trying to find out how to get:

```
1.1        Description 

1.1.1      Quality Assurance 

1.6.1    Quality Control
```

Right now, I have:

```
txt1 <- readLines("text1.txt")

txt2<-grep("^[0-9.]+", txt1, value = TRUE)

file<-write(txt2, "text3.txt")
```

which results in:

```
1.1        Description. 

1.1.1      Quality Assurance 

1.6.1    Quality Control. Quality Control is the responsibility of the contractor.
```

Comment: It seems you already know how to extract section number and text. Why do you find this solution unsatisfactory?

Comment: Hello. I just need help capturing the first sentence after the section number. I already find the line after the section number, but if there is no tab after the first sentence, my result is all the lines following the first sentence, which could be as long as a paragraph. I only want the section number and its name, so up to the first period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using grep with value=TRUE, which

> returns a character vector containing the selected elements of x
>   (after coercion, preserving names but no other attributes).

This means, that if your regular expression matches anything in the line, the all line will be returned. You managed to build your regular expression to match numbers in the begining of the line. So all the lines which begin with numbers get selected.

It seems that your goal is not to select the all line, but to select only until there is a line break or a period.

So, you need to adjust the regular expression to be more specific, and you need to extract only the matching portion of the line.

A regular expression that matches what you want can be:

```
"^([0-9]\\.?)+ .+?(\\.|$)"
```

It selects numbers with dots, followed by a space, followed by anything, and stops matching things when a . comes or the line ends. I recommend the following website to better understand what the regex does: https://regexr.com/

The next step is extracting from the given lines only the matching portion, and not the all line where the regex has a match. For this we'll use the function regexpr, which tells us where the matches are, and the function regmatches, which helps us extract those matches:

```
txt1 <- readLines("text.txt")

regmatches(txt1, regexpr("^([0-9]\\.?)+ .+?(\\.|$)", txt1))
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot! Do you know how you would handle this if there is a tab instead of a space between the section number and the words that comes after it? That was causing me some problems.

Comment: With \\t you can match tabs, or with \\s you can match all whitespace.